# Django query return associative array with distinct fields as keys

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model like this :

```
class Param(models.Model) :
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    default_value=models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
    range=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    order=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    size=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    min=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    max=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    group=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I would like to know how I can with only one query return an associative array with distinct field 'group' as keys

{'group1':[object, object], 'group2':[object, object,object, object]}

For the moment my solution is to first getting the distinct groups and then loop on each and create the dictionnary, but it needs many queries, maybe it can be done faster.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The easiest way is to create a relation with a separate model _Group_, and then check for membership.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you.